# Orthogonal operators over $\mathbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

An operator $T$ over a finite $n$-dimensional inner product space $V$, is orthogonal if $\langle Tv, w \rangle = \langle v, T^{-1}w \rangle$, $\forall v, w \in V$.
Given, $\langle Tv, Tw \rangle = \langle v, w \rangle$, $\forall v, w \in V$. Then how to prove that $T$ is orthogonal?  I have done the converse part which is also true.

Comment: $\langle Tv, w \rangle = \langle Tv, TT^{-1}w\rangle = \langle v,T^{-1}w\rangle$

Comment: Thank you...i got the point..

Answer (score 2):

Since $\langle Tv,Tv\rangle= \langle v,v\rangle>0$ for every $v\ne0$, we see that $Tv\ne0$ for every $v\ne0$. It follows that $T$ is invertible. Consequently, $\langle Tv,w\rangle=\left\langle Tv,TT^{-1}w\right\rangle=\langle v,T^{-1}w\rangle$ for all $v,w\in V$.